# Gem incompatibilities reported by bundler don't make logical sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to update a rails app from version 5.2 to 6. I'm getting bizarre error messages from bundler.

When I change the rails version in my gemfile to 6 and then run `bundle update` I get a series of messages like the following:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)

    seed_dump was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4)
```

Since seed_dump depends on any version of activerecord greater than 4, why doesn't bundle consider version 6 compatible?

What can I do to get `bundle update` to run?

Comment: Have you tried removing the line `BUNDLED_WITH` from `Gemfile.lock` and trying again?

Comment: Thank you, this worked!! If you make the comment into an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: I'd love it if you could explain *why* this was happening, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice in one of the comments, above, I fixed this problem by removing the line `BUNDLED_WITH` from `Gemfile.lock`. After removing the line, running `bundle update` ran without issue.